# Disable tesseract dictionary to improve quality using python

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm using tessract-ocr 4.00 to recognize text on a python application. The problem is that most of my text are non-dictionary type, so to improve the quality of the recognition, the Github page suggest to disable the dictionary. However it happens that this configurable can not be done via the pytesseract - the wrapper library in python.
I dug around and find an other configured option: language_model_penalty_non_dict_word

So by setting that language_model_penalty_non_dict_word=0.0, is this equivalent to load_system_dawg=False in tesseract?

Comment: How did you change language_model_penalty_non_dict_word ? I'm also using pytesseract and I'm struggle to pass my custom variables into config file. Can it be done just by passing it to a 'config' argument in pytesseract functions?

Comment: @Waldemar Kołodziejczyk any resolution?